# Waiting for the text optional module to be downloaded. Please wait. On Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, google-mlkit, image-text

I'm a new android developer and trying to make image to text app. I watched some tutorials and pretty sure that i don't make any mistakes. I'm using ML Kit for this project and got error when i tried to convert the image to text.
My main activity

```
package com.gorkemtand.textrecognition;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.text.Text;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.text.TextRecognition;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.text.TextRecognizer;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.text.latin.TextRecognizerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Permission;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MaterialButton inputImageBtn;
    private MaterialButton recognizeTextBtn;
    private ShapeableImageView imageIv;
    private EditText recognizedTextEt;

    private static final String TAG = "MAIN_TAG";
    private Uri imageUri = null;

    //to handle the result of Camere/Gallery permissions
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    //arrays of permission required to pick image from Camera,gallery
    private String[] cameraPermissions;
    private String[] storagePermissions;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private TextRecognizer textRecognizer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        inputImageBtn = findViewById(R.id.inputImageBtn);
        recognizeTextBtn = findViewById(R.id.recognizeBtn);
        imageIv = findViewById(R.id.imageIv);
        recognizedTextEt = findViewById(R.id.recognizedTextEd);

        cameraPermissions = new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        storagePermissions = new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        textRecognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

        inputImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showInputImageDialog();
                
            }
        });

        recognizeTextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(imageUri == null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Pick image first...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    recognizeTextFromImage();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void recognizeTextFromImage() {

        Log.d(TAG, "recognizeTextFromImage: ");

        progressDialog.setMessage("Preparing image...");
        progressDialog.show();

        try {
            InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(this,imageUri);

            progressDialog.setMessage("Recognizing text...");

            Task<Text> textTaskResult = textRecognizer.process(inputImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Text text) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    String recognizedText = text.getText();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: recognizedText: "+recognizedText);

                    recognizedTextEt.setText(recognizedText);
                }
            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ",e);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed recognizing text due to"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(TAG, "recognizeTextFromImage: ",e);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed preparing image due to"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showInputImageDialog() {

        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, inputImageBtn);

        popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE,1,1,"CAMERA");
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE,2,2,"GALLERY");

        popupMenu.show();
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                int id = item.getItemId();
                if(id == 1){

                    Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Camera Clicked...");
                    
                    if(checkCameraPermissions()){
                        pickImageCamera();
                    }
                    else{
                        requestCameraPermissions();
                    }

                }
                else if(id == 2){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Gallery Clicked...");
                    if(checkStoragePermision()){

                        pickImageGallery();
                    }
                    else{
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private void pickImageGallery(){
        Log.d(TAG, "pickImageGallery: ");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        galleryActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }

    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> galleryActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(

            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                        //image picked
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        imageUri = data.getData();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: imageUri "+imageUri);
                        //set to imageview
                        imageIv.setImageURI(imageUri);
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: cancelled");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cancelled...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
    );
    private void pickImageCamera(){
        Log.d(TAG, "pickImageCamera: ");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Sample Title");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Sample Description");

        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);

        Intent intent  = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
        cameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }

    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cameraActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: imageUri "+imageUri);
                        imageIv.setImageURI(imageUri);
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: cancelled");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    private boolean checkStoragePermision(){
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        return result;
    }

    private void requestStoragePermission(){

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,storagePermissions,STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkCameraPermissions(){
        boolean cameraResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        boolean storafeResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        return cameraResult && storafeResult;
    }

    private void requestCameraPermissions(){

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,cameraPermissions, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    //handle permission results

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if (grantResults.length>0){

                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if(cameraAccepted && storageAccepted){
                        pickImageCamera();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera && Storage permissions are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
            case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:{

                if(grantResults.length>0){

                    boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (storageAccepted) {

                        pickImageGallery();

                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permission is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }


            }
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Also i implemented these two

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2'



implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common:18.0.0'
```

And give the permissions to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And this is the error i got:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djTbY.png)

I searched the google and cnat find a solution. If u can help me i will be very happy.

I searched google and can't find anything works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by implementing `com.google.mlkit:text-recognition:16.0.0-beta6`

Answer (score -1):

Are you testing on device without play store services? For example on an emulator? In order to use com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2 it has to be on a device with play store services.